# Error message in Eclipse: "Program "make" not found in PATH" (C++)

Tags: c++, eclipse, path, makefile

I've been getting the error "Program "make" not found in PATH" in Eclipse (for C++). I searched my computer for make.exe and nothing appeared. I also could not find the folder cygwin, which I saw several people have mentioned when answering similar questions. Is there something I should have downloaded that is the reason for there not being a make.exe on my computer?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need cygwin, unless you want a full POSIX development environment and to compile programs which require POSIX runtime support.

You can get GNU make by installing [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) or by building it yourself; the code is available from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/ and contains a `README.W32` file describing how to compile from source on Windows.

By the way, you should make very clear in your questions that you're talking about Windows platforms (and probably use a Windows tag).